# Resubmit application with same name in different accout - iOS

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, rename

Now I had application name "ABC" in account "X".
I need to bring down the application from account "X".

Then upload application with same name "ABC" in account "Y".

Can it be done?
How do I bring down the application name "ABC" from account "X"?
Can account "Y" upload the application with name "ABC"?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: After transfer the appication, can I change the bundle name with same Application name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not have to delete and reupload it. instead you can transfer an app from one account to the other:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html

Comment: After transfer the appication, can I change the bundle name with same Application name?